# What two probability distributions (other than the Gaussians) convolved together give a Gaussian pdf?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

It is well know that the convolution of two Gaussian probability distribution gives a Gaussian, are there any other choices of initial pdfs that still give a Gaussian after having performed the convultion?

Answer (score 0):

Given that Fourier transform turns convolution into product, the answer is either **trivially no** (the only PDF which convolved with itself gives a Gaussian is Gaussian itself) or **trivially yes** (for any PDF with a nowhere vanishing Fourier transform there is another PDF which convolved with it gives a Gaussian).

Comment: The second part is wrong. If the characteristic function of the given PDF has a zero then you cannot get Gaussian characteristic function by multiplying it with another characteristic function.

Comment: Also I can think to the Fourier transform pair of non-negative integrable functions $\frac{2}{a^2+4\pi^2 \xi^2},e^{-a|x|} (a > 0)$

Comment: @reuns could you elaborate please? I am not sure I follow.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: I think I addressed your concern in an edit.

Comment: @reuns Is that a counterexample to my question?